# Can't access one directory via HTTPS + public FQDN

Tags: iis, https

I have the strangest IIS error that I've ever seen in my life.

I have an application/directory on an IIS server, that throws an error 500 when accessing ANY of the content in it, including HTML documents, when accessed via HTTPS AND the machines FQDN. When I access it with "localhost" it works fine. When I added a bogus entry for the NIC's IP in the hosts file, it worked fine. When I access it with the machines name and HTTP it works fine.

Here's a chart (the machine's name is "lofn.titaniumcrowbar.com"):

http - lofn.titaniumcrowbar.com: works
https - lofn.titaniumcrowbar.com: broken
https - localhost: works
https - temp.titaniumcrowbar.com (put into hosts file): works

I set up tracing, and I got some useless information:

"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)"

This would make sense, except this happens when pulling up *static content*. While the directory may be an "application", the content is all static in it.

Any/all suggestions, no matter how strange, are VERY appreciated.

Thanks!

J.Ja

Comment: What is the result of nslookup inside your network (private or public IP)?

Comment: As stated in the original question, it works fine over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Ping from local PC? Have you checked with Other PCs in your network? There can be issue with DNS.

Comment: As stated in the original question, it works fine over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running IIS7/ASP.NET?  I read an article that outlined a similar issue:

**Cause**
This issue occurs because of an error in the IHttpConnection::IsConnected method. If the IHttpConnection::IsConnected method is called immediately after a Web client connection is dropped, the method incorrectly returns a true value instead of a false value. Therefore, the COMException exception occurs.

This bug is addressed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977453.  If not, do you see anything useful in your IIS or HTTPErr logs?